# UIBarButtonItem getting animated automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, navigationbar

I am facing very weird issue, I am setting childViewController to parentViewController using code:

```
- (void)replaceFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldViewController
               toViewController:(UIViewController*) newViewController {
    [oldViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
    [self addSubview:newViewController.view toView:self.containerView];
    [newViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         // only need to call layoutIfNeeded here
                         [newViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [oldViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [oldViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                         [newViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                         self.currentViewController = newViewController;
                         [self placeButtonForLeftPanel];
                     }];
}
```

and in childViewController which is UIViewController I am adding leftBarButtonItem in this way:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelEdit:)];
```

Now issue is as you can see in .gif file, the cancel button is moving from left to right i.e. it is getting animated, is there way to stop this animation?

[image]

Code for placeButtonForLeftPanel:

```
- (void)placeButtonForLeftPanel {
        UIViewController *buttonController = self.currentViewController;
        if ([buttonController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)buttonController;
            if ([nav.viewControllers count] > 0) {
                buttonController = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
            }
        }
        if (!buttonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem) {
            buttonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftButtonForCenterPanel];
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `[self placeButtonForLeftPanel];`? Also, you are not setting the frame of your `newViewController.view` - please check this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html, chapter `Adding a Child View Controller to Your Content`

Comment: @Losiowaty Added placeButtonForLeftPanel Code. Also set frame for childViewController, still no luck